# Cross Correlation of two arrays in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, correlation

Is there a way to calculate the normalized cross correlation of two arrays in OpenCV (C++)?
[http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/miscellaneous/correlate/](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/%7Epbourke/miscellaneous/correlate/)

I have a `CvMat` and I want to get a correlation matrix of all the cols.
I saw `cvCalcCovarMatrix` but I can't see a way to normalize it to get the correlation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [cvMatchTemplate()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#cvMatchTemplate) with `method=CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED`.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Is there a way to calculate the auto correlation of a matrix where rows are observations and columns variables similar to xcorr in matlab or do I have to do it manually? http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/xcorr.html

Comment: I don't really know. cvMatchTemplate() should work on CvMat matrices too.