# Calculating Covarince matrix using Eigen library, C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I'm trying to do some operations on matrices using a matrix library named, "Eigen Library". I've a 50 X 100000 matrix in size and  I want to find its covariance matrix. So, can I get a built_in function to to find covariance matrix?

C++ sample code:

```
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include "Eigen/Dense"
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
MatrixXf my_matrx = MatrixXf::Random(50,100000);
//Now, i want to find a function to find the covariance matrix of "my_matrx", like below:
MatrixXf my_cov_matrix = any_function(my_matrx);
}
```

Comment: I think this question is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138634/eigen-is-there-an-inbuilt-way-to-calculate-sample-covariance